# Redis to cache a Table with 2 Million Rows

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

We have table in postgres with 2 Million rows, For faster access we would need to cache the data in Redis. How you would cache a table in Redis? For instance take Employee table with Name,Designation,Project,Manager columns. I need to use a Redis Data-structure to store 2 Million Employee rows and possibly query the redis Data Structure with 
`find employees where Designation='Engineer' and Project='Awesome Project'` .Is it possible to cache this Data in redis and have a query to include couple of where conditions?

Comment: Did you check RediSearch?

Comment: Sure, Good to know about RediSearch. I would need redisSearch HA seems it's only available in Redis Labs Enterprise.

Comment: You can run it on Redis open source, Redis Enterprise or Redis Cloud Pro